# Function overloading with different pair types throws

Tags: generics, kotlin, jvm, overloading

So I've overloaded functions such as below:

```
fun putParams(vararg params: Pair<String, String>) {

}
fun putParams(vararg params: Pair<String, Int>) {

}
```

[image]
Could you recommend me the way to avoid this error?

Comment: there are several solutions possible... what is the content of that function? You can use a generic type, e.g. `fun <T> putParams(vararg params : Pair<String, T>)` or use `@JvmName`-annotations... e.g. `@JvmName("putStringParams") fun putParams(vararg params : Pair<String, String>)`... maybe also just `fun putParams(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>)` already suites the purpose...

Comment: Ofc there could be when but one of Pair type is Pair<String, () -> String> do you know how could I check instance ?

Comment: I think it is more interesting what you plan to do inside that function... for now it sounds like a xy problem to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to guess what you really want to accomplish... Here is a solution, that allows either supplying the parameters with a supplier (`() -> Any`) or by passing the actual value (`Any`):

```
@JvmName("putSupplierParams")
fun putParams(vararg params: Pair<String, () -> Any>) = putParams(*params.map { (key, func) ->
    key to func()
  }.toTypedArray()) // just delegated to the following putParams-function

fun putParams(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>) {
    // magic
}
```

Usage would be:

```
putParams("key" to "value")
putParams("key via supplier" to { "supplied value" })
```

An alternative could be:

```
class ParamContainer {
  infix fun <T> String.to(supplier : () -> T) = to(supplier())
  infix fun <T> String.to(value : T) {
    // magic
  }
}
```

(or instead of `T` just `Any`) with the following usage:

```
with(ParamContainer()) {
  "key" to "value"
  "solution" to 42
  "supplied" to {
    "supplied value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to check in when clause if Any is instance of () -> String/Int ?

Comment: still... I guess that this isn't what you really want, but: `value is Function<*>`... I would rather look to partition that variants clearly... there must be a reason why you decided to have some values prepared immediately and some later... so what's the purpose behind that?

Comment: note, that you do not need to delegate the `() -> T`-function to the other... that was just an example... you may rather want to handle that function immediately if that makes more sense to you...

Answer (score 0):

As in Java, Kotlin's type information about generics are available only in compile-time. At run-time `Pair<String, Int>` and `Pair<String, String>` are both appear same to the interpreter. Hence the method signatures are duplicated.

As a solution I would create two separate types.

```
fun putParams(vararg params: StringPair) {..}
fun putParams(vararg params: StringAndIntPair) {..}
```

see [Kotlin Type Erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure)